# How to match the same user in two Apps

Tags: facebook, authorization

user jack login A app by facebook, and login B app by facebook too, how can I make sure they are the same user.
BTW, FB authorized the same user by two differenet access_tokens,how to confirm that jack is jack.

Comment: Are the apps yours? Then use then business mapping API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business